# Two views don't go onto separate lines

Tags: android, button, layout

That's my layout sample code.

I tried to express it with a picture
It's overlapping.
Actually, there's two of them.

https://i.hizliresim.com/LDaAEZ.jpg

https://i.hizliresim.com/PDqkBO.jpg

such a stupid situation

I want to make sub block auto block align
I tried all layouts: Linear-Relative-Grid

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="5">
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="22dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="@string/tmp"
    style="?android:attr/colorButtonNormal" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="22dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/tmp"
        style="?android:attr/colorButtonNormal" />

</GridLayout>
```

---

#### Solved

my solution I fixed this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="22dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="@string/tmp"
    style="?android:attr/colorButtonNormal" />
    <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="22dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="@string/tmp"
    style="?android:attr/colorButtonNormal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what you want to do here?
You want to make screen like https://i.hizliresim.com/PDqkBO.jpg ?

Comment: Hard to explain in English. sorry. because:Needs to come down to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to do like this, you can use `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` etc

here i'm using `LinearLayout` in which i set `android:orientation="vertical"`

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="22dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="22dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="tmp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="22dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="tmp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ı fixed my solution "android:orientation="vertical"" like this

Comment: sorry,Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. doesnt work